# Using printf in java, Making a Factor table and can't get | to align

Tags: java, printf

Please help.

Using `printf` to format a factorial table inside of 2 for loops. 
How can I get the last row to align with the "|"
I need the 0 from the 10 to align with the 9 before it.

Below is my code, I apologize for how messy it looks. I am still learning how to use stackoverflow.

Thank you.

[Factor Table with "|" What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XTXq.jpg)

[Factor Table with "|" What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jLi5.jpg)

```
public void displayTable(){
    System.out.print("    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10" +
        "\n  ----------------------------------------");
    for(int factorNumberDown = 1; factorNumberDown < 11; factorNumberDown++)
    {   
        System.out.printf("\n%1s%s", factorNumberDown, "| ");
        for(int factorNumberAcross = 1; factorNumberAcross <11; factorNumberAcross++)
        {  
           System.out.printf("%4s", factorNumberDown*factorNumberAcross + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to make you aware that your two images are the same.

Comment: Oh my gosh, my apologies. 
Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
"\n%1s%s"
```

with:

```
"\n%2s%s"
```

The complete solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.print("      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10" +
        "\n   ----------------------------------------");
        for(int factorNumberDown = 1; factorNumberDown < 11; factorNumberDown++)
        {   
            System.out.printf("\n%2s%s", factorNumberDown, "| ");
            for(int factorNumberAcross = 1; factorNumberAcross <11; factorNumberAcross++)
            {  
                System.out.printf("%4s", factorNumberDown*factorNumberAcross + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH!!! Haha, 
thank you so much I'm incredibly thankful. 
How did I overlook this?! XD